# calling two API when API realises on information from API one

Tags: reactjs

The first UseEffect calls an API and generates the "Id" needed for the second API to work.
My method seems to be failling.

```
const [randomid, setRandomId] = useState([])
 
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=a5879fe83cace23de294****')
  .then((response) => {
    setRandomId(response.data.results[0])
  })
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
  const users = axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${randomid.id}/videos?api_key=a5879fe83cace23de294d0b28bb3***8&language=en-US`)
  .then(function (response) {
    setkey(response.data.results[0])
  })

}, [randomid])
```

Comment: The `randomid` won't be avaiable in the second `useEffect` method initially. You can call the second API call inside the first `then` logic.

Answer (score 0):

If these two API calls are connected then make them a single operation.  Invoke the second one after the first one is complete:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // make the first API call
  axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=a5879fe83cace23de294****')
    .then((response) => {

      // do you even need this state value by itself anymore?
      setRandomId(response.data.results[0]);

      // make the second API call based on the value from "response"
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${response.data.results[0].id}/videos?api_key=a5879fe83cace23de294d0b28bb3***8&language=en-US`)
        .then(function (response) {
          setkey(response.data.results[0])
      });
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you David, it worked